# Unable to set Test.APIKeyAuthToken

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
public static final String API_TOKEN = "safasfasdfesareasdadasd";
public static final String APIKeyAuthToken = "Auth-Token";
```

But the Auth-Token is not being found in the header request.

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    requestBuilder.addHeader(Test.APIKeyAuthToken, Test.API_TOKEN);
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to send it, then don't set it.

Comment: I want. But not working!

Comment: What does "*not working*" mean? Is the header-value `null`? Is it not set? Is the filter triggered? Please be more specific.

Comment: public static final String API_TOKEN = "safasfasdfesareasdadasd";

    public static final String APIKeyAuthToken = "Auth-Token";

Comment: But, Auth-Token is not found in header request

Comment: Edited the comment into the answer, and formatted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite it is rather unclear which API you are even talking about - and what you might mean with "not working" (this is not an error description at all) ...the HTTP header probably should  look alike:

```
.addHeader("Authorization", API_TOKEN)
```

Just see the API documentation, which string-format is actually being expected... because "not working" might possibly mean, just sending some random header, which the API doesn't accept.